# Font Awesome Icons as a list item or normal background image?

Tags: css, image, list, icons, background-image

Currently I'm using an image as a background for a list of items:

```
.price_item ul li {
  background: url('/images/left_arrow.png') no-repeat right;
  background-size: 12px;
  list-style: none;
 }
```

The image is 725B. However, I'm thinking of replacing this with a Font Awesome icon (font). My question is, in terms of performance and compatibility with different browsers which one is better? I personally think Awesome icon loads faster since it's just a font. In contrast, since using them is not as straightforward as normal background image I'm worried about compatibility. So, is it worth using Font Awesome icon in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You should use font icons. It's very popular now a days and performance wise it's better than images. Below are some benefits.

- Scale with CSS and no problem with Apple's Retina devices.
- You can give any Color by css no need to go to photoshop and change icon color.
- Use multiple icons and overlap icons
- Set opacity or rotate with CSS3.
- No more sprite images for icons.

It's Compatible with IE7 and Above, FF, Chrome, Safari and all other modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, you should use font-icons if you like what you can find. There are a couple of disadvantages though that you have to think of. Script blockers (noScript for firefox for example) usually block webfonts two. You will see a rectangle-error-symbol then. The usage is defenitely a little bit more complicated. The Icons usually don't look as smooth as pngs do as font smoothing is not that good in windows and so on

Comment: @Viken Thanks Viken, now I'm using font icons.

Comment: @RiaElliger Thanks. I didn't know about the rectangle-error-symbol